# Find an upper bound for $T(n)=T(\sqrt{n})+10\log\log n$

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relation, check-my-answer

I need to find an upper bound for $T(n)=T(\sqrt{n})+10\log\log n$.

I thought first to make a substitution: $m=\log n$. Then:
$$
T(2^m)=T(2^{m \over 2})+10\log m
$$
Let $S(m)=T(2^m)$:
$$
S(m)=S\big({m \over 2}\big)+10\log m
$$

Now we can use Master theorem.

Suppose it's the case when $f(m)=O(m^{\log_2 1-\epsilon})=O(m^{0-\epsilon})$. Let $\epsilon=0.5$ then:
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{10\log m}{m^{0.5}}=0
$$
Hence according to the Master theorem $T(m)=\Theta(m^0)=\Theta(1)$.

Am I in the right direction?

Comment: We don't grade answers here. Keep working until you get an answer. If all steps you did along the way were valid, then you will have found the correct answer.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I don't think the answer is correct actually I now realized that $f(m)\neq O(m^{0-\epsilon})$. I don't think master theorem is applicable here right?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus on a separate note, I didn't make up the tag "check-my-answer" so I don't think I'm misusing the platform in any way. I think it's always better to show your line of thinking and get feedback as opposed to just ask a question and receive an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run time of a Simple Recurrence](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/77776/run-time-of-a-simple-recurrence)

Comment: Yos, you might want to look at the guidance for the [tag:check-my-answer] tag: https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/check-my-answer/info.  As Yuval says, we discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as they tend not to be interesting or useful to future visitors.  See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/).

Comment: In the future, I encourage you to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about. As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can expand the recursion (ignoring the constant 10) as follows:
$$
\begin{align*}
T(n) &= \log \log n + \log \log n^{1/2} + \log \log n^{1/4} + \log \log n^{1/8} + \cdots \\ &=
\log \log n + \log \frac{1}{2} \log n + \log \frac{1}{4} \log n + \log \frac{1}{8} \log n + \cdots \\ &=
\log \log n + (\log \log n - \log 2) + (\log \log n - \log 4) + (\log \log n - \log 8) + \cdots
\end{align*}
$$
At this point, let us notice that the number of terms is roughly the value of $k$ satisfying $n^{1/2^k} = \Theta(1)$, which translates to $\frac{\log n}{2^k} = \Theta(1)$ and so $\log n = \Theta(2^k)$, implying $k \approx \log_2 \log n = (\log \log n)/\log 2$. Keeping $k$ symbolic at first, we have
$$
\begin{align*}
T(n) &= k \log\log n - (\log 2)(0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots + (k-1)) \\ &=
k \log\log n - \frac{\log 2}{2} k(k-1) \\ &\approx
k \left(\log\log n -\frac{\log 2}{2} k \right).
\end{align*}
$$
Substituting our approximation for $k$, we deduce
$$
T(n) \approx \frac{\log \log n}{\log 2} \left(\log\log n - \frac{\log\log n}{2}\right) = \frac{(\log \log n)^2}{2\log 2}.
$$
In particular, $T(n) = \Theta((\log \log n)^2)$.

Comment: Wow. Why $n^{1/2^k} = \Theta(1)$? As far as I understand $k$ is the height of the tree of recursion? Then wouldn't it be $2^k=n$ but because we have $T(\sqrt{n})$ I'd figure $(2^k)^{1/2}=n^{1/2} \Leftrightarrow 2^{k/2}=\sqrt n \Rightarrow n=\log{k \over 2}$

Comment: The recursion stops once you reach some base case, and this happens when $n^{1/2^k}$ dips below some constant.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative solution still using domain transformation/[change of variables](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3482/changing-variables-in-recurrence-relations).

$$T(n) = T(\sqrt{n}) + \log \log n$$

#### 1. Let $m = \log n$

We can then define a new function $S$ based on how $m$ changes in $T$ and expand it:

$$\begin{align}
S(m) &= S\left(\frac{m}{2}\right) + \log m\\
&=S\left(\frac{m}{4}\right) + \log m -1 + \log m\\
& \vdots\\
& = \log^2 m - \sum_{i = 1}^{\log m} i \\
& = \Theta(\log^2 m) \implies T(n) = \Theta((\log \log n)^2) 
\end{align}$$

#### 2. Let $k = \log \log n$

We can then define a new function $R$ based on how $k$ changes in $T$ and expand it:

$$\begin{align}
R(k) &= R(k - 1) + k\\
& = R(k - 2) + k - 1 + k\\
& \vdots\\
& = \Theta(k^2) \implies T(n) = \Theta((\log \log n)^2)
\end{align}$$

Comment: if $m=\log n$: let $m=2^k$ then as far as I understand the development is $\log m+\log{m \over 2}+\log{m \over 4}+...+\log{m \over k}=\log m+\log m -\log 2+ \log m -\log 4+...+\log m-\log k=m\cdot \log m-\sum_{i=1}^{2^k}\log 2^i=m\cdot \log m-\frac{\log m(\log m +1)}{2}=m\cdot \log m-{1 \over 2}(\log^m+\log m)=\Theta \log ^m$. Is this correct?

Comment: I've made one edit expanding the step you mention. The problem in your comment is $\dots  \neq m \cdot \log m - \dots$, it should be $ = \log m \cdot \log m - \dots$, because the expansion will only continue as many steps as we can divide $m$ by $2$, which would be $\log m$.

Comment: And regarding your second method why if $k=\log{\log n}$ then $\sqrt n=k-1$?

Comment: I kinda hid the assumption that $n = 2^{2^k}$ and also hid the assumption that log bases were 2 but that's typically assumed. So we then have $\sqrt{2^{2^k}} = 2^{2^{k-1}}$. Check [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/77779/68251) for more info.

Comment: The point of $R$ is to represent *just* how $k$ changes in the recurrence $T$. $R$ is different than $T$, but if we get a bound on $R$ we can infer a bound on $T$. Establishing $T(\sqrt{n}) = T(2^{2^{k-1}})$ would leave us in the same place we started just in a different form. $R$ abstracts the difficulties of $T$ by only dealing with the variable $k$ rather than $2^{2^k}$.

Comment: Yes, I understood that in the end after you get $\sqrt n=2^{2^{k-1}}$ then because $k=\log \log n$ we "unroll" $2^{2^{k-1}}$ by $\log{\log{2^{2^{k-1}}}}$

Comment: One last question: is there a formula for  $\sum_{i=1}^{\log m}
 i$? I didn't find anything on google so far

Comment: It's just the sum of 1 to $\log m$. Check [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+1+to+n). The main idea is that $\sum_1^n i = \Theta(n^2)$ for any $n$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62167/discussion-between-yos-and-ryan).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose  $n=2^k.$

By substitution method we can extend the recurrence relation as follow:
$$T(n)=T(\sqrt{n})+\log\log n$$
$$=\hspace{4pt} T\left(\sqrt{\sqrt{n}}\right)+\log\log n+10\log\log\sqrt{n}$$
$$=\hspace{4pt} T\left(\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{n}}}\right)+\log\log n+\log\log\sqrt{n}+\log\log\sqrt{\sqrt{n}}$$

$$\dots =\hspace{4pt}T\left(n^{\frac{1}{2^k}}\right)+\log\log n+\log\log\sqrt{n}+\log\log\sqrt{\sqrt{n}}+\dots+\log\log n^{\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}}$$

After simplifying the logarithm terms:
$$\dots =\hspace{4pt}T\left(n^{\frac{1}{2^k}}\right)+\log\log n+\log\left(\frac{\log n}{2}\right)+\log\left(\frac{\log n}{4}\right)+\dots+\log\left(\frac{\log n}{2^{k-1}}\right)$$
Next step is trying to find the value $k$:
$$ n^{\frac{1}{2^k}}=\mathcal{O}(1)\implies  k=\log\log n$$
(In essence, we need the height of recursion tree $\mathcal{T}$
that you can define the height $\mathcal{H}(n)$ of $\mathcal{T}$ as a recursion formula $\mathcal{H} (n)=\mathcal{H} (\sqrt{n})+1$, after solving it you get $\mathcal{H}(n)=\mathcal{O}(\log \log n).$

Finally we can write $T(n)$ as a summation:
$$T(n)=\mathcal{O}(1)+\sum_{i=0}^{\log\log n} \log \left(\frac{\log n}{2^i}\right)$$
$$=\hspace{4pt} \mathcal{O}(1)+\sum_{i=0}^{\log\log n} (\log \log n- i)$$

$$=\hspace{4pt} \mathcal{O}(1)+\sum_{i=0}^{\log\log n}  i=\theta(\log^2\log n)=\theta(\log\log n)^2$$